# Extjs - Change default invalid field messageTarget on labelAble style

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

In extjs, is there any way to change a property for a specific type of control across the entire project from one place, essentially making it the default value for this property on all new instances of that class?

In particular, I want to change all the [msgTarget](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#%21/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-msgTarget)'s on all field controls from 'qtip' to 'side'.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Ext.onReady( function() { 

    Ext.override( Ext.form.Labelable, {
         msgTarget: 'side'
    });

});
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615817/how-to-extend-override-a-predefined-core-sencha-class/13617177#13617177) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that is working for me is something like this:

```
Ext.define('FooMsgTargetOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.Base',
    msgTarget: 'under'
});
```